# cannot Set the datasource on a datapresenter that has items added explicitly through data items collection

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I have a collection in MainViewModel ,as

```
     View = new List<Group>
            { 
                new Group
                {
                    Name = "Sagar Yadwad",GroupName = string.Empty,IsEnabled = true,LdapStatus="Pending"
                },
                new Group
                {
                    Name = "Sagar Yadwad1",GroupName = string.Empty,IsEnabled = false,LdapStatus="Pending"
                }

            };
        View1 = new ListCollectionView(View);

        View1.Filter = (e) =>
        {
            Group g = e as Group;
            return g.IsEnabled;
        };
```

Now, I am binding my above ViewModel to my XamDatagrid and the code is as follow :-

```
          <igDp:XamDataGrid x:Name="XamDataGridGroup"  DataSource="{Binding View1}" Width="950"   FontStyle="Normal" FontFamily="Siemens Sans" Background="#F2F2F2" RecordFilterDropDownPopulating="GroupDataGrid_OnRecordFilterDropDownPopulating"  GroupByAreaLocation="None" AllowDrop="True" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" UpdateMode="OnUpdate" >
                <UserControl>

                </UserControl>
                <igDp:XamDataGrid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDp:DataRecordPresenter}">
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding DataItem.IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey {x:Type igDp:XamDataGrid}, ButtonStyle}" BasedOn="{StaticResource  BaseButtonStyle}"/>
                    <Style TargetType="igWindows:PopupResizerBar" >
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </igDp:XamDataGrid.Resources>
                <igDp:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
                    <igDp:FieldLayoutSettings AllowRecordFixing="No"  
                                      AllowDelete="False"
                                      HighlightAlternateRecords="False" 
                                      RecordSelectorLocation="None"
                                      SelectionTypeRecord="Single"  
                                      SelectionTypeCell="Single" FilterUIType="LabelIcons"
                                      AutoGenerateFields="False" AllowFieldMoving="No"
                                      RecordSelectorExtent="1"/>
                </igDp:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>


                <igDp:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings >
                    <igDp:FieldSettings  
                LabelTextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                FilterLabelIconDropDownType="MultiSelectExcelStyle"  
                AllowRecordFiltering="True" AllowCellVirtualization="False" 
                AllowLabelVirtualization="False" Width="Auto" CellWidth="100"
                CellMinWidth="50"/>
                </igDp:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
                <igDp:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
                    <igDp:FieldLayout>
                        <!--<igDp:FieldLayout.Fields>
                <igDp:Field Name="Name" AllowEdit="False" AllowRecordFiltering="True"></igDp:Field>
            </igDp:FieldLayout.Fields>-->
                        <igDp:UnboundField  Width="300"  Label="{LocText props:Resources.GROUPLIST_NAME}" BindingPath="Name" ToolTip="{LocText props:Resources.GROUPLIST_NAME}">

                            <igDp:UnboundField.Settings>
                                <igDp:FieldSettings>
                                    <igDp:FieldSettings.LabelPresenterStyle >
                                        <Style  TargetType="igDp:LabelPresenter"  BasedOn="{StaticResource GmsLabelStyle }">
                                            <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="Groups_Column"></Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </igDp:FieldSettings.LabelPresenterStyle>
                                    <igDp:FieldSettings.CellValuePresenterStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDp:CellValuePresenter}">
                                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"></Setter>

                                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="igDp:CellValuePresenter">
                                                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.DataItem.Name,  RelativeSource={ RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
                                                        <!--Visibility="{Binding Path=Parent.IsNameChangeable}"/>-->

                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </igDp:FieldSettings.CellValuePresenterStyle>
                                </igDp:FieldSettings>
                            </igDp:UnboundField.Settings>

                        </igDp:UnboundField>
                        <igDp:UnboundField Width="350" Label="{LocText props:Resources.GROUPLIST_LDAP_USERS}" BindingPath="GroupName" ToolTip="{LocText props:Resources.GROUPLIST_LDAP_USERS}">

                            <igDp:UnboundField.Settings>
                                <igDp:FieldSettings>
                                    <igDp:FieldSettings.LabelPresenterStyle >
                                        <Style  TargetType="igDp:LabelPresenter"  BasedOn="{StaticResource GmsLabelStyle }">
                                            <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="Group_Name"></Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </igDp:FieldSettings.LabelPresenterStyle>
                                    <igDp:FieldSettings.CellValuePresenterStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDp:CellValuePresenter}">
                                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"></Setter>

                                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="igDp:CellValuePresenter">
                                                        <TextBlock AllowDrop="True"  Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.DataItem.GroupName,  RelativeSource={ RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"  TextAlignment="Center" />
                                                        <!--Visibility="{Binding Path=Parent.IsNameChangeable}"/>-->

                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </igDp:FieldSettings.CellValuePresenterStyle>
                                </igDp:FieldSettings>
                            </igDp:UnboundField.Settings>

                        </igDp:UnboundField>
                        <igDp:UnboundField Width="100" Label="{LocText props:Resources.GROUPLIST_SYNC}" BindingMode="TwoWay"  BindingPath="IsEnabled" Converter="{StaticResource BoolToUMDirectoryFilter}" ConverterParameter="Enabled"  ToolTip="{LocText props:Resources.GROUPLIST_SYNC}">
                            <igDp:UnboundField.Settings>
                                <igDp:FieldSettings AllowEdit="True">
                                    <igDp:FieldSettings.LabelPresenterStyle >
                                        <Style  TargetType="igDp:LabelPresenter"  BasedOn="{StaticResource GmsLabelStyle }">
                                            <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="Group_SYNC"></Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </igDp:FieldSettings.LabelPresenterStyle>
                                    <igDp:FieldSettings.CellValuePresenterStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDp:CellValuePresenter}">
                                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"></Setter>
                                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="igDp:CellValuePresenter">
                                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=DataContext.DataItem.IsEnabled,  RelativeSource={ RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                                                          HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">

                                                        </CheckBox>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </igDp:FieldSettings.CellValuePresenterStyle>
                                </igDp:FieldSettings>
                            </igDp:UnboundField.Settings>
                        </igDp:UnboundField>
                    <igDp:UnboundField Width="140" Label="{LocText props:Resources.GROUPLIST_LDAP_STATUS}" BindingPath="LdapStatus" ToolTip="{LocText props:Resources.GROUPLIST_LDAP_STATUS}">

                        <igDp:UnboundField.Settings>
                            <igDp:FieldSettings>
                                <igDp:FieldSettings.LabelPresenterStyle >
                                    <Style  TargetType="igDp:LabelPresenter"  BasedOn="{StaticResource GmsLabelStyle }">
                                        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="Group_Status"></Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </igDp:FieldSettings.LabelPresenterStyle>
                                <igDp:FieldSettings.CellValuePresenterStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDp:CellValuePresenter}">
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"></Setter>

                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="igDp:CellValuePresenter">
                                                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.DataItem.LdapStatus,  RelativeSource={ RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                                                           VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                                                    <!--Visibility="{Binding Path=Parent.IsNameChangeable}"/>-->

                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </igDp:FieldSettings.CellValuePresenterStyle>
                            </igDp:FieldSettings>
                        </igDp:UnboundField.Settings>

                    </igDp:UnboundField>
                </igDp:FieldLayout>
                </igDp:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
            </igDp:XamDataGrid>
```

I am getting an error saying that, ' cannot Set the datasource on a datapresenter that has items added explicitly through data items collection '. Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance,
Sagar Yadwad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `UserControl` from the `XamDataGrid`:

```
<igDp:XamDataGrid x:Name="XamDataGridGroup"  DataSource="{Binding View1}" ...>
    <UserControl>

    </UserControl>
...
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply worked like charm for me :)